# Ошибка с vk_api python

Tags: python-3.6

Русский язык. При отправлении сообщения боту на русском языке, консоль выводит ошибку. При отправлении на английском - все в порядке.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="токен")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
for event in longpoll.listen():
         if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('Сообщение пришло в: ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")))
            print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
            print(event.user_id)
```

Comment: Токен введен,я его скрыл специально.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @Xander Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/123", line 12, in <module>
    print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: У вас точно Python 3.6, а не Python 2.7?

Comment: @andreymal да,стояла 2.7,забыл сменить. Теперь все работает,спасибо

Comment: @TheButterShow уберите из кода `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` — В Python 3 это не нужно, зато вы точно больше не запустите случайно код в Python 2